# onEditSubmit not binding the submission correctly

Tags: reactjs

I have an app that I need to be able to EDIT the amount of likes on an object. When I submit the new value into the desired field, it hold the value for a second and then resets it back to the original value.

the Edit submit code:

```
onEditSubmit (name, likes, originalName) {
    let dataSource = this.getDataSource();

    dataSource = this.state.dataSource.map((dataSource) => {
      if (dataSource.name === originalName) {
        dataSource.name = name;
        dataSource.likes = likes;
      }
      return dataSource;
    });
    this.setState({dataSource});
}
```

the on Edit submit event handler:

```
  onEditSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.props.onEditSubmit(this.nameInput.value, this.likesInput.value, this.props.name);
    this.setState({ isEdit: false });

  }
```

and my input fields:

```
<form onSubmit={this.onEditSubmit}>
              <input placeholder="Name" ref={nameInput => this.nameInput = nameInput} defaultValue={name}/>
              <input placeholder="Likes" ref={likesInput => this.likesInput = likesInput} defaultValue={likes}/>
              <button>Save</button>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a race-condition issue. `.setState()` is asynchrounous for performance reasons, and so you should use its `callback` method when attempting to change the state synchronously.

Try doing this:

```
onEditSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let name = this.nameInput.value
    let likes = this.likesInput.value
    let originalName = this.props.name

    this.setState({ isEdit: false }, () => {
        this.props.onEditSubmit(name, likes, originalName);
    });
}
```

## EDIT

It also looks like your `dataSource` obj is constantly being reassigned. Try this as well:

```
onEditSubmit (name, likes, originalName) {
    let dataSource = this.getDataSource();

    var newData = this.state.dataSource.map(data => {
      if (data.name === originalName) {
        return {name, likes}
      }
    });

    this.setState({dataSource: newData});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However the same behavior is occurring.

Comment: I edited my question with my form code to show what's going on there as well.

Comment: @dksmith328 It looks like you were also assigning your variables incorrectly, try implementing my edit as well and let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to use `filter` instead of `map`.

```
onEditSubmit(name, likes, originalName) {
    // following line does not make much sense to me. commenting it out
    // let dataSource = this.getDataSource();

    // using filter will give you the data that has name matching to orignalName
    var dataSource = this.state.dataSource.filter(data => {
      return data.name === originalName;
    });

    this.setState({dataSource});
}
```

Although, it would be more helpful if you can also post some information on the `dataSource` for `this.state.dataSource`.
Right now, it is kind of hard to understand the current state structure of `dataSource` and what you are trying to set.
Try the above solution and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your suggestion. This new code didn't store my new value and it cleared the entire list after submission. I posted my full code to a new thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550721/oneditsubmit-not-storing-the-new-value-correctly)